# Setting PI decimal places to user given number of places in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a simple operation where I display the value of PI to a user declared decimal length.  For instance, if a user enters 2, PI will print out 3.14.  However, I keep getting an `ArgumentsOutOfBounds` error.  Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class PiToDecimalPlaces{
    public static void Main(){
        int decimalPlaces = (int)Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine(Round(decimalPlaces));
    }
    public static double Round(int places){
        double piToPlaces = Math.Round(Math.PI, places);
        return piToPlaces;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the exception, exactly ?

Comment: Call `Console.ReadLine` and `int.TryParse` instead of just casting the character code to `int`.

Comment: @Pac0 sorry, this one `double piToPlaces = Math.Round(Math.PI, places);`

Comment: Try to output the value of  `places`, or inspect it in the debugger, just before the exception. You will see that there is something weird. And the comment of @MichaelLiu is the explanation and the solution.

Comment: @MichaelLiu, that did it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things.

First: The below line is logically incorrect. The output returned by Read is a `char` in the `int` variable

```
int decimalPlaces = (int)Console.Read();
```

What you need is

```
int decimalPlaces = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Second: Your function should really use `decimal` and not `double` when you want to do fixed point precision since `double` is a floating point precision value

```
public static decimal Round(int places){
    decimal piToPlaces = Math.Round((decimal)Math.PI, places);
    return piToPlaces;
}
```

This should fix your exception and also, avoid any potential Floating Point Precision issue

Answer (score 0):

When you directly read using `Console.Read()`, you're reading the `ASCII` value of input into the `decimalPlaces`.

So if you entered `2`, the value of `decimalPlaces` would be `50`.

What you need to do is use `Console.ReadLine()` and do `int.TryParse()` on the input, and then pass it to your `Round()` method.

```
string strNum = Console.ReadLine();
int decimalPlaces;
int.TryParse(strNum, out decimalPlaces);
Console.WriteLine(Round(decimalPlaces));
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my reply so edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the line you are reading value from console to,

```
int decimalPlaces = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```